# Form doesn't work without double click

Tags: jquery, function, form-submit

I have a problem with a form function in jQuery. It forces me to double click in order to submit the form.

```
<script>  
function pin_login(forma) {
    jQuery("#form_" + forma).submit(function (e) {

        var value_pin = jQuery(".pin_" + forma).val();
    });
}
</script>
```

Every time I double click it works, but it doesn't work when I single click, it doesn't submit the form. To clarify, I want it to submit one a single click, not a double.

Comment: What are you using `e.preventDefault();` for?

Comment: How are you calling `pin_login()`? Can you show the relevant parts of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `e.preventDefault()` your form should not return after second or third or nth clicking of submit.

If you want to submit you need to return `true` without calling `e.preventDefault()` like in the example below.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  if ( correct )
     return true;
  else {
     $("#error").text("Not valid!") ;
     return false;
  }
});
```

Calling `e.preventDefault()` or returning `false` will prevent submitting your form to the server.

Now, since `e.preventDefault()` prevents form submitting and you claim that your form does it, so I claim that your code from the example is never called. Can you copy paste more, please? Or maybe you can use jsfiddle...

Comment: I delete prevent default and continue need 2 click for send the submit form

Comment: As I said - e.preventDefault() will block *always* submission. That means that your code is not called if the form submits. You need to debug it, or, you may use jsfiddle and present us with not working example.