# Double submit required for send form

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have a little problem with my form, i need push over the submit button 2 times, my script it's this:

```
<script>  
function login(id) {
    jQuery("#form_" + id).submit(function () {

        var value_pin = jQuery(".pin_" + id).val();
    });
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="form_ini" name="form" method="post" action="?" onsubmit="login('ini');return false;">

<input name="pin_vps" id="cp_input" type="text" class="pin_vps" value="">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

This works after i push over submit 2 times, if no, no works finally.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where is the submit element?

Comment: No understand you sorry

Comment: Onsubmit call function and inside works the jquery

Comment: you need to show that code, then

Comment: All code i have it´s that you see i put ? this works but i need give 2 times for send the form but works , and it´s all code i have

Comment: Are you the same person as posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540083/form-doesnt-work-without-double-click/18541071#18541071 or this is homework for a class? :D

Comment: that code does not submit the form, that code attaches an event handler to the sumbit event. what is actually firing the submit event? usually it is an input element with type=submit.

Comment: Yes man i forget put the buttom but sure you can supose i put buttom for send the form it´s the logic

Comment: I put the submit buttom

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details however try these two approaches, i simplified your approach just to show you how to submit the form, the reason you need to double post its because the first click sets up the event and you return false, so you need to click it again in order to fire the event.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" > </script> 
</head>
<body>
<form id="form_1" name="form" method="post" action="?" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input name="pin_vps" id="cp_input" type="text" class="pin_vps" value="">
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" data-ini="1" />
</form>


<script>  
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#form_1").submit(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" > </script> 
</head>
<body>
<form id="form_1" name="form" method="post" action="?">
  <input name="pin_vps" id="cp_input" type="text" class="pin_vps" value="">
  <input name="submit" type="button" value="Send" id="submit" data-ini="1" />
</form>


<script>  
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var value_pin = $(this).data("ini");
    alert("test");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `return false` in your `onsubmit` attribute. That prevents the form from submitting. It calls `login()`, which replaces the submit handler with the new function, which doesn't return `false`. So the next time you submit the form, it works.

Change to:

```
function login(id) {
    var value_pin = jQuery(".pin_" + id).val();
    // Do something with value_pin
}

$(function() {
    $("#form_ini").submit(function() {
        login("ini");
    });
});
```

and remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the `<form>`.